# Form Button disabled appearance

Tags: c#, forms

I have a series of buttons which I enable and disable programmatically for various reasons. I was unhappy with the default appearance of a disabled button. So I modified my code to also change the BackColor when it disables a button. This works, but now the button has a thick grey border when it is disabled. I tried changing the BorderColor and the Border size, but this has no effect. How can I get rid of the border?

```
this.EditButton.Enabled = false;
this.EditButton.BackColor =  ColorTranslator.FromHtml(ControlColours.DisabledButtonBackColour);
this.EditButton.BorderColor = ColorTranslator.FromHtml(ControlColours.DisabledButtonBackColour);
this.EditButton.FlatAppearance.BorderSize=0;
```

Comment: web? winforms? wpf? silverlight?

Comment: Sorry. It's a c# form application

Comment: You need to show your code for that buttons.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of

```
this.EditButton.BorderColor = ColorTranslator.FromHtml(ControlColours.DisabledButtonBackColour);
```

this one

```
this.EditButton.FlatStyle = FlatStyle.Flat;
```

Comment: Yes that fixed it. Thank you so much.